# required modules in a webpack bundle are undefined

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, require

I am building a javascript library and using the require() method to require external modules into other modules. My problem is the modules I require are not defined. I can see all the modules are in the webpack output file but at run time the required modules return undefined.

I did an experiment and moved the module which is getting required into another one at the top of the output file, this way the required module is loaded by the browser first. This fixed the problem.

For example:

```
// main.js
var moduleA = require('./module.a.js');

var main = (function() {
    "use strict";


    return {
        moduleA: moduleA
    }
})();

exports.main = main;



// module.a.js
var moduleA = (function() {
    "use strict";



    return {
        myMethod: myMethod
    }
})();

exports.moduleA = moduleA;
```

currently my webpack.config.js defines that the entry file is main.js

```
    var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var libraryName = "myLib";

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/modules/main.js',
  output: { 
    path: __dirname+"/build", 
    filename: libraryName+'.all.js',
    library: libraryName,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve('./src/')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // JS
      {
        test: /.js/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

This is causing main.js to get loaded into the output file first, if manually reordering the modules in the output file so moduleA is read first before my main module, how can I fix this with webpack? My other webpack build has the entry file at the top of the output file, but it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use vastly simplified modules once you start using Webpack. You don't have to wrap things in IIFE's. CommonJS modules (which you're building when you use Webpack) automatically do everything cleanly and never pollute the global scope. You only expose what you put in `module.exports`.

Try the following:

```
// main.js
"use strict";

var moduleA = require('./module.a.js');

// do something with moduleA.myMethod()

module.exports = "Whatever you want to export";
```

and

```
// module.a.js
"use strict";

function myMethod() { 
  return "something";
}

module.exports = { myMethod: myMethod };
```

Nothing else is needed. This will work with the output Webpack gives, you should never have to change anything in Webpack's output. Webpack will automatically execute the requires to instantiate the modules for you when they are needed, in the right order.